# Connection not available in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I have the following configuration in `application.conf` for an in-memory database HSQLDB:

```
db {
   inmemory {
       jndiName = jndiInMemory
       driver = org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
       url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:inmemory"
  }
}
```

And connect in a controller with the following statements

```
val database = Database.forName("jndiInMemory")
val session = database.createSession
val conn = session.conn
//  JDBC statements
```

Problem is that when the code runs several times, I get an exception in  `session.conn`:

> HikariPool-34 - Connection is not available, request timed out after
>   30000ms.

Since I'm using JNDI, I figured that the connections are reused. Do I have to drop the session after I finish using it? How to fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without looking at the actual code but in general: when you create a database connection at the start of the application, you usually reuse it until application ends - then you should close connection.

If you spawn a new connection every time you do query, without ending previous ones you will run at the connection limit pretty fast.

Easy to use pattern is: create a session in the beginning and then use dependency injection to pass it to wherever you need to run it.

BTW, I noticed that for some configurations e.g. Slick create connection statically (as in: stores them as static class properties). So, you need to create a handler, that closes session when application exits. It run ok... until you start it several times over in SBT, which by default uses the same JVM to run itself and spawned application. In such cases it is better to run things as fork. For tests I use `Test / fork := true`, for run I use [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver), though I am not sure how that would play out with Play.

Comment: Injecting the connection solved the problem. thanks.